# PHP Fatal Error - $wpdb a non-object?

Tags: wpdb, fatal-error

I'm getting many Fatal errors like this in Wordpress 3.6.1, multisite with Buddypress:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function suppress_errors() on a non-object in /myblog/wproot/wp-includes/option.php on 
line 143`

The non-object referred to is the global value $wpdb, in the line:

`$suppress = $wpdb->suppress_errors();`

which is in the function **wp_load_alloptions()**

Any ideas why $wpdb would not be set, and if there is anything to be done to remedy this? Sorry I don't have any more useful on this, the errors are isolated and don't show a stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

"the errors (…) don't show a stack trace" - they would if you were using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org).

It means `$wpdb` is not loaded yet, not loaded properly, or gone:

- If you added code that calls it to your wp-config file or something to that order, remove it.
- If you've a db.php file in wp-content, it's probably broken so rename it.
- If you're messing around with things on a shutdown handler, do them earlier on the shutdown hook instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have xdebug on my dev server, but unfortunately can't reproduce these errors there.
I will look into your third suggestion, though if that's the case it will be in a third party plugin.